# Should it be continual or continuous?

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence in question:

•   Dedicated to *continuous* learning in the workplace.
•   Dedicated to *continual* learning in the workplace.

I also feel that the sentence needs to be simpler.

Comment: why not "continued learning"?

Answer (score 1):

Continuous indicates duration without interruption while *continual* indicates duration over a period of time, with interruption.

Consider the following example from [Daily Writing Tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/continuous-or-continual/),

> The continual street repair disrupted traffic for nearly two years.

The sentence above indicates that the repair is ongoing over two years but is interrupted at certain intervals.

Now consider this use of 'continuous':

> The continuous humming of the fluorescent lights gave him a headache.

This sentence implies that the humming is happening uninterruptedly over a period of time.

Now, in your case, if you intend to say that you were dedicated to scrupulously learning with no pause or interruption, *continuous* would be the word  you're looking for.

However, *continual* would be the better choice if you were looking to say that the dedication was to learning *over a period of time* in the workplace.

Edit:

I retract my last statement about continual being the better choice.

[image: ngram graph]

It seems like continuous learning is the better phrase to use.

Comment: I agree with everything except the last point.  "Continuous learning" is the idiomatic way to say that you're always learning.  Saying "continual learning", while grammatically correct, doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: +1 Ah right, my bad. I wasn't aware of the idiomatic usage of "continuous learning."

Comment: I *don't* agree with everything. Specifically, I do *not* agree that something which happens *continually* necessarily implies ***interruptions***. It's true that *continuous* implies ***no** interruptions*, but *continually* is "orthogonal" to that - it just implies *for a long time* more strongly than it implies *uninterrupted*. But it's very much more likely to be ***negative***, so we don't use it so often with good things like "learning".

Comment: I'm just wondering. Would "Dedicated to *continued* learning in the workplace." be another grammatically correct version? In what way might it alter the meaning of the expression?

Comment: I'm not sure what the NGram really proves - although one is more popular, both phrases are in common usage. Personally, *continual learning* doesn't sound all that awkward, although it's true that it could imply a longer period of time. *Continued learning* might simply imply that it is continuing an already started process (e.g., building on learning from university).

Answer (score 0):

"Continuous" or "continuously" means "without interruption".

> The annoying garage band in my neighborhood played music continuously throughout the morning yesterday.

"Continual" or "continually" is more akin to "repeatedly".

> My co-workers were continually interrupting me throughout the day today.

For your example, you should use "continuous".  Learning is not really a single event that you could say happens repeatedly.