# "Continuously" vs "continually": What's the difference?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

What's the difference in the usage of these two adverbs *continuously* and *continually*?

Here are some examples:

> a) She was told off for **continually** being late.
>
> b) It rained **continuously** for three hours this morning.
>
> c) The firemen worked **continuously** through the night.
>
> d) I'm afraid you **continually** make the same mistakes.

Comment: *Continuously* describes an activity that doesn't stop once an instance of it begins. *Continually* describes an activity that is on going, but which may start and stop. There can be some overlap between the two.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Please edit the question to provide more information, in order to enable a quality answer. Do read our [help on asking questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Ensure that you include all the research you have done already, and indicate what isn't clear in the information you found. This ensures that people don't repeat the work you have already done, and can address exactly what you're unsure of. I found [this in Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g05.html) from an online search.

Comment: Seems like a dupe of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116568/should-it-be-continual-or-continuous

Answer (score 5):

Continuously comes from continous (meaning without break) and continually comes from continues.  You use continuously in b) and c) because these are actions that continued without pause or breaks.  You use continually in a) and d) because they are actions that happen over and over again.  In other words, continually is used for discrete or repeated actions whereas continuously is used for continuous ones.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples of *continually* you could always substitute the word [habitually](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/habitually). Here, *continually* refers to the habits of people.

Your examples of *continuously* **may** have to do with people (in the case of the firemen). But they refer not to habits, but instead, to some action of persons or machines or events (in your example of rain) that are performed without a break.

Answer (score 1):

*continuously* or *continually*?

> **Continual** means frequently recurring or intermittent. **Continuous** means occurring without interruption or unceasing. **Continuous** refers to actions which are uninterrupted: The upstairs neighbor played his stereo **continuously** from 6:00 PM to 3:30 AM. **Continual** actions, however, need not be uninterrupted, only repeated: My mother **continually** urges me to do my homework. / Rivers flow **continuously**, but the telephone is more likely to ring **continually**. A related mistake is to use **continuous** for something that happens at regular intervals. There are other adjectives that mean 'occurring repeatedly over a long period of time': "constant" (implying persistence, steadiness), "ceaseless" and "incessant" (referring to uninterrupted activity), "eternal" (lasting forever), "interminable" (seemingly endless, wearisome), "perennial" (going on year after year, with self-renewal), and "perpetual" (implying both duration and steadiness). So, try to remember to use *-al* for something which is either always going on or recurs at short intervals and never comes to an end, and *-ous* for something in which no break occurs between the beginning and the end.
>   (Dictionary.com Word FAQs *[When should I use continuously as opposed to continually?](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g05.html)*)

Answer (score 1):

As recorded by Fowler- (p.178)

> Continually had been used to mean both 'incessantly,constantly, all
>   the time' and less strictly (OED) with frequent repetition, very
>   frequently'.
>
> Continuously is used when the unbroken nature of a process (in space
>   or time) or set of events (e.g. unbroken terms of office) is being
>   stressed.

- **The choice is largely governed by the degree with which continuity is
  being emphasized.**

  - I'm afraid you continually make the same mistakes.

Or simply put-
when you do something **continually**, you may take breaks in between, but when you do it **continuously**, you don't stop at all. Continually is good for describing something you do repeatedly, or on a regular basis.
 (vocabulary.com)