# Use of continuously to describe a act

Tags: word-choice

I’m struggling with the use of “continuously” in the following sentence.

> Is it distressing to continuously finish one assignment only to be issued
>   another?

Does it describe the act of finishing one assignment or does it describe the whole process of finishing one assignment and being immediately issued another?

I think it’s not needed, but the writer really wants to emphasize the tedious nature of the job.

Comment: Did you compare definitions for continuous and continual?

Comment: When a punctual activity is repeated, the repetition can be thought of as a continuous process, and terms applicable to such may be used of it. Much as the individual repeated explosions in an internal combustion engine combine to produce a continuous roar. As for _continuous_ vs _continual_, forget it; nobody uses them for any such distinction.

Comment: "Continually" means "repeatedly".  "Continuously" means "without interruption.

Comment: Once you finish a task what else would you do but start another? It is called [work](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work). Not having another task is called unemployment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Continuously" vs "continually": What's the difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230887/continuously-vs-continually-whats-the-difference) Although this earlier question was closed, the reason wasn't that the question was of no lasting interest; the cited problem was that the poster hadn't included any research in the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

A better word for "continuously" might be "repeatedly". The case of having a new task to perform once the first is done is what is continuous. Continuously could make it seem the first task is never finished.

Comment: Nice answer. However on SE EL&U we'd prefer a link to an online dictionary to support your argument. That way the OP can check that you are correct, as can anyone else who has the same problem. It may seem trivial, but I thought I'd mention it as it's your first post. See  [the answers help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that to convey the tedious nature of the job the sentence

> Is it distressing to continuously finish one assignment only to be
>   issued another?

could be

> Is it distressing to finish one assignment only to be endlessly issued
>   with more?

with **endlessly** moved to the second part of the sentence.

An assignment is not continually completed. It is the following assignments that keep on coming.

Answer (score 0):

"..to continuously finish" is oxymoronic. 
"Is it distressing to work continuously?"
"Is it distressing to work on endless tasks?" 
"Is the endless nature of the work distressing?"
"Is it distressing to complete many tasks without accomplishing a goal?"
"Is work distressing?"
Answer: "yes, continuous feed back loops cause me distress"

Answer (score 0):

"Continuously" does carry the sense of 'uninterrupted'.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/continuously

In that sentence, I would be more likely to use "constantly" (in my whiny teenager voice), which would mean 'continually recurring'. 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constantly (Definition 3)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you’ve got yourself stuck in a hole, focusing on an inappropriate title, and asking the wrong question.

### By labeling your question, “Use of continuously to describe a(n) act,” and centering your question on trying to find out more about the word, “continuously,” you’re robbing yourself of the opportunity to find an answer to what you really came here to get help with – which appears to be *creating a sentence that “emphasizes the tedious nature of the job.”*

It was not until you finished asking your question that led you astray that you finally got around to making a comment that revealed your real reason for coming here to ask for help.

Referring to the word, “***continuously,”*** you said, “I think it’s not needed, but the writer ***really wants to emphasize the tedious nature of the job.”***

**If it’s the tedious nature of the job that your “writer” wants you to communicate, you’re, unfortunately, going about it all wrong.**

**You’ve allowed yourself to get hung up on trying to get information about the word, “continuously.”**

Whether or not “continuously” “describes the act of finishing one assignment” or “describes the whole process of finishing one assignment and being immediately issued another” is not the issue here and is not going to lead you in the direction of creating a sentence that will accomplish the goal of “emphasizing the tedious nature of the job.”

### I suggest you start out by changing your title to something that’s more likely to get you some answers that relate to what you’re trying to accomplish.

> Consider changing the title to something like,
>
> "Creating a sentence that emphasizes the tedious nature of the job."

### Then re-word your question also.

> Consider perhaps changing your question to something like,
>
> “I’ve been given an assignment to write about a particular job, and
>   I’m stuck.  The writer I’m writing this for wants me to *emphasize the
>   tedious nature of the job,* and the sentence I’ve written is,
>
> 'Is it distressing to finish one assignment only to be issued
>   another?'    "I thought the sentence did a good job of doing what the
>   writer said he wanted, but he thinks that if I add the word,
>   “continuously,” the sentence will do a better job of *emphasizing the
>   tedious nature of the job.*”  I’m struggling with the use of the word,
>   “continuously.”  I don’t think it’s needed.  I  would appreciate
>   suggestions for improving this sentence and helping to make it
>   *emphasize the tedious nature of the job*.”

(You get the idea, Debbie.  You are welcome to use the parts of this paragraph that work for you in re-wording your question so you’ll get responses that are more helpful to you.)

### Now, for some tips to help you answer your own question:

**Pay attention to the meanings of words.**

The first thing you need to do once you find out what you’re supposed to be communicating is to gather up some words that describe the “thing” you’re supposed to communicate.

In this case, that “thing” would be, *“the tedious nature of the job.”*

If you’re expected to write a sentence that communicates, *“the tedious nature of the job,”* it would be helpful for you to know what, “tedious,” means and to pay attention to that meaning as you re-write your sentence.

The same goes for other words you’ll be using in writing and re-writing sentences now and in the future.

That should be your starting point.  Bother to find out the meanings of the words in the sentences that are provided in your assignment, and look up the meanings of words you think you might want to use (They may not always mean what you’ve always assumed they mean.)

That doesn’t necessarily mean you’ll be using many or even a few of the definitions or synonyms in the sentences you’re creating, but it’s important to have a good sense of the meaning of the target word while you’re choosing other words to create a meaningful sentence around it.

In this case, the primary target word is, "tedious."

If, after collecting your list of definitions and synonyms, you end up having the opportunity to use some of those words as modifiers in what you’re writing, all the better.  That can help to emphasize the message you’re trying to communicate, and add powerful meaning to what you write.

An easy way to find definitions of a word is to go to [www.Google.com](http://www.Google.com) and type in the word.  Hit “Enter,” and a page of links to various online dictionaries featuring that word will appear.

Sort through the words, and do a Copy & Paste of the ones that appear to be useful for your purpose.  You can paste your collection of words either into a word document or an email – or even write them on a sheet of paper.  The main thing is to put the definitions and synonyms in a place where you can organize them into a useful list that you can look at while you’re creating your work.

```
    (Links to the online dictionaries and thesauri used for the definitions and synonyms here and throughout this document will appear at the end of this response.)
```

These words listed here (in alphabetical order) came from [www.Dictionary.com](http://www.Dictionary.com) and other online dictionaries -- from definitions for the word, "Tedious."

- Boring

  Causing fatigue

  Dull

  Frustrating

  Monotonous

  Tiresome by reason of length

  Too long

  Too slow

These words (in alphabetical order) came from [www.Thesaurus.com](http://www.Thesaurus.com)

They are synonyms for the word, "Tedious."

- dreary

  drudging

  endless

  fatiguing

  exhausting

  ho-hum

  humdrum

  laborious

  lifeless

  long-drawn-out

  repetitive

  slow

  tiresome

  tiring

  unexcitings

  uninteresting

  wearisome

**Okay.  Now you have a list of words that mean, “tedious.”  This will make it much easier to successfully create a sentence that *“emphasizes the tedious nature of the job.”***

> The sentence you were struggling with is:
>
> “Is it ***distressing*** to ***continuously*** finish one assignment
>   only to be issued another?”

You say you need for the sentence to *emphasize the tedious nature of the job*.

Okay, we can work within the framework of that sentence to make it do what you’ve been assigned to make it do.

First, you’ll need to get rid of the modifiers that DO NOT do an especially good job of *emphasizing the dull, boring, tedious nature of the job* -- 
and replace them with words that support the definitions and synonyms you’ve gathered from the dictionaries and thesauri online -– words that DO do a good job of emphasizing those meanings.

---

**Out with the old:**

The meaning of ***“distressing”*** in the sentence you’re struggling with is, *“upsetting, frightening, causing anxiety or stress.”*

So, the word, ***“distressing,”*** in that sentence would not be the best adjective to describe the emotional state of a person trapped in a *dull, boring, monotonous, tedious job.*

The meaning of, ***“continuously”*** means *repeatedly without interruption* – which has nuances of what you’re trying to describe, but fails to paint the word picture it needs to paint in order to *emphasize the tedious nature of the job.*

The word, ***“continuously”*** doesn’t do much to communicate the *uninteresting, wearisome, “never-endingness” of the tedious assignment* the worker is doing now, that feels like “*forever*” – with *no relief visible* on the horizon.

“*Mind-numbing*” would be a better choice.  But there are other words that would do as well – as long as the words take into account the fact that the tedious job the person is doing is the polar opposite of exciting and motivating.

**So, We need to get rid of *“distressing”* and “*continuously,”* and replace them with better words.**

> Your original sentence:  “Is it ***distressing*** to
>   ***continuously*** finish one assignment only to be issued another?” (with "distressing" and "continuously" removed becomes:
>
> "Is it ________________ to ______________ finish one assignment only
>   to be issued another?"

**In with the new:**

The word, ***“discouraging”*** means *causing someone to lose confidence or enthusiasm; depressing.*

The word, ***“discouraging”*** instead of, *“distressing,”* paints a better picture of what the *tedious job* does to the emotional state of a person trapped in such a job.

The word, “***finally,***” instead of, “*continuously*,” is very descriptive of the point in the process that the worker eventually reaches after *enduring long periods of drudgery and boredom* associated with the *dull routine* of such a *tedious job*.

***Finally, FINALLY!*** The worker gets to the point where he thinks he’s *finally at the end of the seemingly endless monotony* of the job he’s been *doing for who-knows-how-long* -- only to be *immediately* issued yet another *equally mindless and meaningless chore* he’s expected to do – *without so much as a break* in between.  He’s *slapped in the face* with the *grim reality* that he’s *not at the end* – and *probably never will be*.  It’s an *endless stream* of *one tedious assignment after another*, with *no blissful end in sight*.

> So, your original sentence:
>
> “Is it ***distressing*** to ***continuously*** finish one assignment
>   only to be issued another?” becomes:
>
> “ Is it ______________ to _________ finish one assignment only to be
>   issued another?
>
> (Fill in the blanks, and the sentence becomes:
>
> “Is it ***discouraging*** to ***finally*** finish one assignment only
>   to be issued another?”

This is a much stronger sentence than the one you were originally struggling with.

The weak, misused modifiers in your original sentence have been replaced by stronger, specifically appropriate modifiers that do a ***pretty good job*** of accomplishing your goal of *“emphasizing the tedious nature of the job*.”

There.   All done.

But ARE we?

**Is that the best we can do?  I don’t think so.**

What if – now that we have all those definitions and synonyms for the word, *“tedious”* – we make use of some of those descriptive words to *strengthen the emphasis of the “tedious nature of the job?*”

Let’s use some of those adjectives to add descriptions to that notorious job whose nature is so *tedious.*

> So, now, your improved sentence,
>
> “Is it **discouraging** to **finally** finish one assignment only to
>   be issued another?”
>
> becomes another Fill-In-The-Blanks sentence:
>
> “Is it ***discouraging*** to ***finally*** finish one  ___________, 
>   ___________,  ___________  assignment only to ___________ be issued another?”
>
> Let’s use some of those definitions and synonyms to fill in the
>   blanks.
>
> “Is it ***discouraging*** to ***finally*** finish one  ***dull*** , 
>   ***boring*** ,  ***seemingly never-ending***   assignment only to ***immediately***  be issued another?”

This long and complicated sentence, of course, goes way beyond the limits of your intended assignment, but gives you a taste of what words can accomplish if you pay particular attention to their meaning.

So, now you’ve got several levels of finished product – from *fairly simple*, to *fairly complicated* – and a number of Fill-In-The-Blank sentences you can use to experiment with different words on your own.

> ### Completed sentence # 1
>
> **“Is it *discouraging* to *finally* finish one assignment only to be
>   issued another?”**
>
> ### Completed sentence # 2
>
> **“Is it *discouraging* to *finally* finish one *dull*, *boring*,
>   *seemingly never-ending* assignment only to *immediately* be issued another?”**

Now, you have a sentence that paints a picture that emphasizes the tedious nature of the job!

Hopefully, you can use some of the tips I’ve provided you here to help you write stronger, more meaningful sentences.

You don’t have to make your sentences complicated, as I did here.  You can keep your sentences simple at first, and your skills will grow as you gain experience.

Good luck in your writing endeavors.

---

### Links to Online Dictionaries and Thesauri (plural of Thesaurus)

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tedious?s=t
Definition of 'tedious'
[tee-dee-uh s, tee-juh s] 
See more synonyms on Thesaurus.com
adjective
1.
marked by monotony or tedium; long and tiresome:
tedious tasks; a tedious journey.

---

https://www.google.com/search?q=tedious&oq=tedious&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2424j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
Online Dictionary
te•di•ous
ˈtēdēəs/
adjective
1.  too long, slow, or dull: tiresome or monotonous.
"a tedious journey"
synonyms:
boring, dull, monotonous, repetitive, unrelieved, unvaried, uneventful; 
characterless, colorless, lifeless, insipid, uninteresting, unexciting, uninspiring, uninvolving, flat, bland, dry, stale, tired, lackluster, stodgy, dreary, mundane, monochrome; 
mind-numbing, soul-destroying, wearisome, tiring, tiresome, irksome, trying, frustrating; 
informal deadly, not up to much, humdrum, ho-hum, blah, dullsville, 'same old, same old'
"work on the assembly line was tedious"

---

Thesaurus.com
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tedious?s=t
Synonyms for tedious
adj dull, monotonous
•   boringstar
•   drearystar
drudgingstar
dull
•   endlessstar
•   fatiguing
•   exhaustingstar
ho-humstar
•   humdrumstar
•   laboriousstar
•   lifelessstar
•   long-drawn-outstar
•   monotonous
•   slowstar
•   tiresomestar
•   tiringstar
unexcitingstar
•   uninterestingstar
•   rwearisome
https://www.google.com/search?q=distressing&oq=distressing&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2j69i60j0l2.4615j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
Online Dictionary
dis•tress•ing
dəˈstresiNG/
adjective
1.  causing anxiety, sorrow or pain; upsetting.
"some very distressing news"

---

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/distressing?s=t
Definition of Distressing
[dih-stres] 
Spell Syllables
See more synonyms on Thesaurus.com
noun
1.
great pain, anxiety, or sorrow; acute physical ormental suffering; affliction; trouble.
2.
a state of extreme necessity or misfortune.

---

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/distressing
Thesaurus.com
Synonyms for Distressing
•   deplorablestar
•   dreadfulstar
•   frighteningstar
•   painfulstar
•   regrettablestar
•   troublesomestar
•   naggingstar
•   distressfulstar
•   fearfulstar
•   grievousstar
•   woeful

---

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/continuously?s=t
Definition of Continuous
[kuh n-tin-yoo-uh s] 
Spell Syllables
•   Examples
•   Word Origin
See more synonyms on Thesaurus.com
adjective
1.
uninterrupted in time; without cessation:
continuous coughing during the concert.
2.
being in immediate connection or spatial relationship:
a continuous series of blasts; a continuous row of warehouses.

---

https://www.google.com/search?q=discouraging&oq=discouraging&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i60j0l3.2192j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
Online Dictionary
Definition of Discouraging
disˈkərijiNG/
adjective
1.  causing someone to lose confidence or enthusiasm; depressing.
"a discouraging experience"

---

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discouraging?s=t
Definition of Discourage
[dih-skur-ij, -skuhr-] 
•   Synonyms
•   Examples
See more synonyms on Thesaurus.com
verb (used with object), discouraged, discouraging.
1.
to deprive of courage, hope, or confidence; dishearten; dispirit.

---

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nuance?s=t
Definition of nuance
[noo-ahns, nyoo-, noo-ahns, nyoo-; French ny-ahns] 
See more synonyms on Thesaurus.com
noun, plural nuances 
 [noo-ahn-siz, nyoo-, noo-ahn-siz, nyoo-; French ny-ahns] (Show IPA)
1.
a subtle difference or distinction in expression,meaning, response, etc.
2.
a very slight difference or variation in color or tone.

---