# please help me with this

Tags: grammar

can anyone help me with this:” I shivered and sweated ______ .” I’m wavering between “continuously” and “ continually “. I googled it and found that the answer is “ continually “ but my teacher said the correct answer  is “ continuously “. pls tell me which one is correct and enlight me on the difference between them. thanks in advance and sorry for my terrible english

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Continuously" vs "continually": What's the difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230887/continuously-vs-continually-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 1):

Both words are **adverbs**, and grammatically speaking, you **can** use both to fill in the blank space.

> **Continuously** means *without a pause or interruption*
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/continuously)

> **Continually** means *in a way that happens repeatedly*
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/continually)

**However**, like what your teacher has said, I also think that **continuously** might be a better choice because there are no other signs in your sentence to show the repetition. It seems to me that the act of shivering and sweating here refers to a continuous action at a fixed point in time that might have lasted for a short period.

- I shivered and sweated continuously after seeing the exam paper.

But if you use the word continually, I think you have had several rounds of shivering and sweating (with certain starts and stops in time).